# Matlab function for cumulative power

Tags: matlab

Is there a function in MATLAB that generates the following matrix for a given scalar `r`:

```
1 r r^2 r^3 ... r^n 
0 1 r   r^2 ... r^(n-1)
0 0 1   r   ... r^(n-2)
...
0 0 0   0   ... 1
```

where each row behaves somewhat like a power analog of the CUMSUM function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`cumprod`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumprod.html) and [`triu`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html):

```
% parameters
n = 5;
r = 2;

% Create a square matrix filled with 1:
A = ones(n);
% Assign the upper triangular part shifted by one with r
A(triu(A,1)==1)=r;
% cumprod along the second dimension and get only the upper triangular part
A = triu(cumprod(A,2))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can compute each term directly using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) and [element-wise power](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/power.html), and then apply [`triu`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triu.html):

```
n = 5; % size
r = 2; % base
result = triu(r.^max((1:n)-(1:n).',0));
```

Or, maybe a little faster because it doesn't compute unwanted powers:

```
n = 5; % size
r = 2; % base
t = (1:n)-(1:n).';
u = find(t>=0);
t = t(u);
result = zeros(n);
result(u) = r.^t;
```

Comment: Ho nice ! (just need to set the lower triangular part to zero)

Answer (score 1):

Well, `cumsum` accumulates the sum of a vector but you are asking for a specially design matrix, so the comparison is a bit problematic....
Anyway, it might be that there is a function for this if this is a common special case triangular matrix (my mathematical knowledge is limited here, sorry), but we can also build it quite easily (and efficiently=) ):

```
N = 10;
r = 2;
% allocate arry
ary = ones(1,N);
% initialize array
ary(2) = r;
for i = 3:N
    ary(i) = ary(i-1)*r;
end
% build matrix i.e. copy the array
M = eye(N);
for i = 1:N
    M(i,i:end) = ary(1:end-i+1);
end
```

This assumes that you want to have a matrix of size `N`x`N` and `r` is the value that you want calculate the power of.

**FIX**: a previous version stated in line 13 `M(i,i:end) = ary(i:end);`, but the assignment needs to start always at the first position of the `ary`

Comment: There's a small fix: `M(i,i:end) = ary(1:end-i+1);`